# How to create a JSON view from a domain object?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm creating the server side implementation of an AJAX based web application, where the client side receives responses that are domain objects serialized as JSON.  In order to provide a common look and feel, I would like to create templates for different types of domain objects, and re-use these as Spring views for multiple controllers.

For instance, say I have the following object graph:

A - B - C

where A and C have a many-to-many relationship.  When I return an object of type A as the result of an AJAX request, I would like to return its associated data in the B and C tables.  However, when I return an object of type C as the result, I would like to return just the data in table C.

Thus far the only solution I have found is to create a custom data binder in the controller; however I believe this use case is better suited as a view that can be shared among many controllers.  Does a solution for this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have views that are JSON-formatted versions of your model.

Take a look at [Spring-Json view](http://spring-json.sourceforge.net/) and the `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView` class.

Comment: Very cool, I was actually wondering about this earlier today.

Answer (score 1):

[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) has a [JSON serializer and deserializer](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/json/package-summary.html) for arbitrary Java objects.